# how to edit selected item in listview in wpf c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a list I want to edit one item in that list but I do not know what it says.

```
 private void Listview_asset_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = listview_asset.Items[0].ToString();



    }
```

Comment: Seems to me you are trying to convert an object to a string. Try creating an object instead and edit the properties accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The `Items` property on a `ListView` object is a collection of objects. As such you won't get the text displayed back from the `ToString()` like you're expecting, you will just get the string representation of the object.

You need to retrieve the object from the `ListViewItem` and then pick the property you want. As the object is stored as an `Object` you'll have to to a know type on the way out in order to access properties.

Here's an example below to get you started.

```
// Setup
listView.Items.Add(new ABTest()
{
    A = "A 1",
    B = "B 1"
});
listView.Items.Add(new ABTest()
{
    A = "A 2",
    B = "B 2"
});

// Change Listener        
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ABTest ab = (ABTest)listView.SelectedItem;
    string str = ab.A;
}
```

Comment: I'm using WPF, not Windows form, and this command is unusable here

Comment: @pmsmasoud I've edited to be appropriate to WPF now, sorry I hadn't noticed when I first read this. Let me know if this helps, if not edit your question and add your setup code and I can take a more in-depth look

Comment: I did not understand what code you wrote
Do you have a watts app or any other social network that I can say exactly where it is?

Comment: @pmsmasoud No sorry I can't give out that information on here. Could you edit your post and include your setup code where you add your your items to the list view? That will allow me to edit the answer to contain a specific example to your code rather than a generic one

Comment: I do not know how to send the program file here. How can i send it?

Comment: @pmsmasoud There should be an edit button on your question when you hover over it. Click to edit there and you will be able to include more information in the original question